# button redirect using php

Tags: php, html, redirect

I have this simple code that I was reviewing to figure out what is making nothing happen. Before you tell me to just use `onclick="";` or to put an `action` in the form, I need you to know that I understand that I can do it those ways.  But that is not my goal. My goal is to figure out why this way is not working. So please keep those kinds of comment to yourselves! That being said here is the code in question:

```
<form method="POST" action=""><button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">CheckOut</button></form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $result = true;
        if($result){
            header("Refresh: 2; url='checkout.php'");
        }
    }
?>
```

Now when the button is clicked, nothing happens. Is there a simple reason when this code doesn't execute how I think it should be? (That is redirect the user to the `checkout.php` page?)

Answer (score 1):

Try using input type as below.  And also PHP tag not closed properly.

```
     <input type="submit"  name="submit"  value="Submit" >
```

Comment: The php tag was just a mistake typing the questions, thanks for pointing it out though, if fixed it. Also i tried this and still receiving the same results. click the button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

**Fixed:**
I believe you have a typo when closing php tag, ">?" not "?>"

**Edit:**

The original code worked fine for me, you can also try:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    header("Location: checkout.php");      
}
?>
<form method="POST" action=""><input type="submit" id="submit" value="CheckOut" name="submit"></form>
```

If it makes any difference...

Comment: I addressed this issue, it was just a mistake typing the question, the actual code is fine. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
header("Refresh: 2; url='checkout.php'");
```

with

```
header("location:checkout.php");
exit;
```

Comment: Same result, Click the button, nothing happens. Thank you for a timely response though. Any other suggestions? or do you know why the code in question is not working? Is there an obvious mistake?

Comment: Mistake what i see is the tag is not properly closed. Should be `?>` instead of `>?`

Answer (score 0):

There can be no output before the header(), so the HTML code you have placed before the header() is causing it not to work.
php manual: [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)